# Sequelize retornando [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou tentando renderizar no template `index.handlebars` o parameter `productName`em uma tag `<p>`, que recebe a informação do attribute `product_name` da tabela definida. utilizando o findAll() do Sequelize, mas é retornado como [object Object], desta forma: `<p>[object Object]</p>`.

Não consegui encontrar uma resposta que me ajude, estou há dias tentando entender o Sequelize.

Segue abaixo os códigos.

No template `index.handlebars` temos uma tag `<p>` que irá receber o `productName`:

```
<p>{{product_name}}</p>
```

Este é a tabela definida no sequelize, já exportada para o server:

```
const Product = db.sequelize.define('products', {
  product_name: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
  },
  product_description: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
  },
  product_image: {
    type: db.Sequelize.BLOB('medium')
  },
  on_slider: {
    type: db.Sequelize.TINYINT
  }
})
```

E por fim, a função para capturar um nome e renderizar na página:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Product.findOne({
      attributes: ['product_name'],
      raw: true
    }).then(
      function(productName) {
        res.render('home', {product_name: productName})
      }
    )

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo que você colocar para trazer apenas o atributo `product_name`, o *Sequelize* irá te devolver um objeto, que por sua parte terá apenas a propriedade `product_name`.

O parâmetro que você está recebendo na sua função de callback, o qual você está chamando de `productName` é um objeto, não uma string.

O certo seria

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Product.findOne({
      attributes: ['product_name'],
      raw: true
    }).then(
      function(product) {
        res.render('home', { product_name: product.product_name })
      }
    )
});
```

Ou alternativamente você poderia desestruturar esse objeto diretamente na declaração do argumento:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Product.findOne({
      attributes: ['product_name'],
      raw: true
    }).then(
      function({ product_name }) {
        res.render('home', { product_name })
      }
    )
});
```

Comment: Funcionou! Agradeço Muito!
E caso eu queira passar dois parâmetros no render? Exemplo:

Tenho o {{product_name}} sozinho e um {{#each products}} com expressões dentro dele, mas não consegui fazer com que ambos fossem carregados. Tentei instanciar com uma função, atribuir como variáveis etc. e acabei encontrando impasses.
Como ficaria neste caso?

Comment: @Caio, abra uma pergunta com todos os detalhes. Você pode encontrar exemplos genéricos na internet, se eles não te ajudaram, então não é o meu exemplo genérico que irá resolver seu problema.

Comment: criei uma nova [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540140/passar-m%c3%baltiplos-par%c3%a2metros-par%c3%a2metros-no-render). Agradeço muito.